# Show desktop makes desktop icons refresh (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop

Just upgraded to Windows 10. All working fine, except that when I click Show desktop, it correctly switches to the desktop, but all icons disappear for about a third of a second, then reappear. Just once. Quite irritating. Never happened in previous Windows versions I had.

It happens whether there are twenty icons on the desktop or just one. At first I thought it might be because of PDFs on the desktop, so I removed them, but still the problem.

My graphics driver is up-to-date.

More info:
When I open File Explorer (not maximized) the desktop icons around the edges of the new window do not disappear and reappear. But if I open any other program (not maximized) the icons do disappear/reappear. And switching back to the desktop from either File Explorer or any program, when the latter are maximized, the desktop icons disappear/reappear.

I suspect some program might be causing the issue. I briefly had Adobe Acrobat installed, but uninstalled it. Could it be that?

Windows key + M tends not to cause the desktop icons to disappear/reappear, but I think they do sometimes.

Comment: Show Desktop (lower right corner) is a toggle. Desktop goes away and comes back. I think what you are seeing is normal.

Comment: Thanks, John. On Windows 7, for example, it doesn't do it. I still have Windows 7 on another drive, and have just tested it. If others get the same thing on Windows 10, then maybe it is normal.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, I'm really not so sure it's normal. As mentioned in my post, when opening a non-maximized window the desktop icons disappear and reappear - and that's not a case of toggling between the desktop and a program. It's simply opening a program.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone has any thoughts on this, or solutions? As I say, it didn't happen in Windows 7.